# Firestore recursive collections backup

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Is it possible to backup a hierarchy of collections?

we store the data as:

```
 * users
     * user1
         * userInfo (on the user1 document)
         * accounts
             * account1
             * account2
         * jobs
             * job1
             * job2
             * job3
     * user2...

 * chats
     * chat1
         * chat metadata (on the chat document)
         * messages
             * message1
             * message2
         * chatUsersInfo
             * userInfo1
             * userInfo2
             * userInfo3
```

(There're also deeper sub-collections)

I'm using this example for the backup job https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/schedule-export

Is there a way to backup the data as is and not only its first level documents?

Is it possible to restore only part of the hierarchy (i.e - restore user1 data)?

Is there a way to exclude some collections from the backup (i.e - jobs)?

Comment: When you say *backup*, what do mean? What's the use case?

Comment: I would like to be able to restore the data (to same firestore instance) in case of flows error that may lead to data lost. i.e- developer may delete one of the collection by accident and we'll need to restore it

Comment: I am not a Firebaser but they do make backups of data in case of data loss. You can optionally back your Firebase up to your device by writing the code to read the data and then save it locally in whatever format you like. And as you mentioned, export the data via Cloud Functions. If you need specifics about Firebase backups at a server level, you should reach out to [Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support) directly as that goes beyond the scope of what we can help with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Is it possible to backup a hierarchy of collections?

You can only filter specific collections by using the `collectionsIds` field. Here is an example using the [`gcloud firestore export` command](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/export-import#export_specific_collections).

In general if you need to backup just specific data you'll need to create an application that make the relevant query to read the relevant collection or document you are interested in and saving it in whatever format you consider more convenient anywhere you'd like (e.g. Cloud Storage).

- Is there a way to backup the data as is and not only its first level documents?

As I already advised on the previous question if you are only interested in making a backup of specific data within your whole Firestore instance, you'll need to make an application in order to query the specific data that you want to export (please refer to the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#web) for the specific query that you'll need: either list subcollections in a document or get multiple documents from a collection group, etc.)

- Is it possible to restore only part of the hierarchy (i.e - restore user1 data)?

You won't be able to restore a specific part of a hierarchy, but you'd be able to [import only a specific set of collections using the collectionsIds field](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/export-import#import_specific_collections) in a similar fashion to:

gcloud firestore import gs://[BUCKET_NAME]/[EXPORT_PREFIX]/ --collection-ids=[COLLECTION_ID_1],[COLLECTION_ID_2]

- Is there a way to exclude some collections from the backup (i.e - jobs)?

Notice that as explained on your [example shared](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/schedule-export) you can use the `collectionsIds` field to create a list with only the collections you want to export (and therefore by not adding the collections that you don't want to export you can exclude them from the export operation).

```
  return client.exportDocuments({
    name: databaseName,
    outputUriPrefix: bucket,
    // Leave collectionIds empty to export all collections
    // or set to a list of collection IDs to export,
    // collectionIds: ['users', 'posts']
    collectionIds: []
    })
```